# Can't access internet with 32-bit browser(Chrome, FF, IE)! The 64-bit version of IE on Win 7 works fine

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virus, kaspersky

I had installed Kaspersky AV 2010 two days ago. Everything was fine until I was not able to access the internet a few minutes back with the 32 bit browsers I have installed - Chrome, Firefox and the 32 bit IE. Then I see that utorrent is working fine!! So again I checked with the 64 bit IE and I could access the internet. I am currently using IE 64 bit to access superuser. Please help! I have uninstalled the KAV 2010. I thought that was the problem. Is this any virus or something?
Also, whenever any browser (except IE 64), the screen freezes. Nothing except the browser works! And after the browser is closed, everything comes back to normal.
Thanks!

Comment: I am also not able to connect through Yahoo Messenger :( .. I cant understand how the 64-bit IE is working and 32 bit not!! Please help !!

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. Now I am currently using the 32 bit browser as they are working. What I did was installed Trend Micro Internet security ans it found 15 malwares. Other I did a winsock reset as I read i on some forum.

Now everything is working fine.

Comment: I have had an issue similar to yours with an expired, corrupt version of Norton 360 where Norton unsuccesfully acting like a proxy.  Norton wouldn't unistall so I had to use a Norton Removal kit.  All was fine once removed.